# how to set the python framework path before building cxfreeze for python3

Tags: python, build-process, python-3.x

I m building a python script using a setup.py file. In building process, it links to python framework. I want to change the linking framework path as its linking to the wrong location.
How to set the framework path before building the script.

Thanks in advance for sparring ur valuable time for this thread.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your cxFreexe is installed with and run with the same python as you run the application you want to freeze. That way your PYTHONPATH should be set up correctly.

The exception is if the script you want to freeze itself modifies Python path. In that case you need to make the same modifications yourself before freezing.